# Recursion for Catalan number to Memoized

Tags: java, catalan

I have been asked to write a recursive function that will calculate the Catalan number of monotonic lattice paths along the edges of a grid with n × n square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal ([pic](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Catalan_number_4x4_grid_example.svg/1035px-Catalan_number_4x4_grid_example.svg.png))
I was not allowed to use for-loops, only recursive calls... This is what I did:

```
public long C(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    return C(n, 0, 0);
}

private long C(int n, int i, int j) {

    // CAN MOVE UP & RIGHT
    if (j - i > 0 && j + 1 <= n)
        return paths(n, i + 1, j) + paths(n, i, j + 1);
    // CAN MOVE UP
    else if (j - i > 0)
        return paths(n, i + 1, j);
    // CAN MOVE RIGHT
    else if (j + 1 <= n)
        return paths(n, i, j + 1);
    // CAN'T MOVE
    else
        return 1;
}
```

I don't know if this code is the best but it works... I want to convert this function to be a Memoized function. But I can't understand how & also why it would make the function more efficient. I understand why Fibonnaci in memoized is more efficient, but here I will always have to get to the end of the path and then return 1 or 0 so what does it matter if I store 1 / 0 inside an array for say?
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: It's pretty easy getting it memoized. Is that all you need?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth hey, yes thank you

Comment: Gimme one mo. Should be done

Comment: There you go. Hope that does it. There isn't more to it than that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you know what Memoization is. Basically, all you do is create a table `memo` which stores a value once you reach it so you don't have to calculate it in the recursion again. Something similar to why `fibonacci(5)` won't have to go into recursion to find `fibonacci(3)`, if we have already calculated, say `fibonacci(6)`, because we have *memoized* it. I hope you get it. Here is the code, memoized in the same spirit. Andrea's question has great visuals to understand.

```
long[][]memo;  //Memo table

public long C(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;

    memo=new int[n+1][n+1]; //Increase to n+1 and won't crash!

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
            memo[j][i]=-1;

    return C(n, 0, 0, memo);
}

private long C(int n, int i, int j, it) {

    // CAN MOVE UP & RIGHT
    if (j - i > 0 && j + 1 <= n)
    {
        if(memo[i+1][j]==-1)
            memo[i+1][j]=paths(n, i + 1, j);

        if(memo[i][j+1]==-1)
            memo[i][j+1]=paths(n, i, j + 1);

        return memo[i+1][j]+memo[i][j+1];
    }
    // CAN MOVE UP
    else if (j - i > 0)
    {
        if(memo[i+1][j]==-1)
            memo[i+1][j]=paths(n, i + 1, j);
        return memo[i+1][j];
    }
    // CAN MOVE RIGHT
    else if (j + 1 <= n)
    {
        if(memo[i][j+1]==-1)
            memo[i][j+1]=paths(n, i, j + 1);
        return memo[i][j+1];
    }
    // CAN'T MOVE
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but it crashes (out of bounderies exception)... I think it happens because I refer index 0,0 as the bottom left, and then when I move right I check `<= n` like I should but there is no such index in memo. Do you know how ti fix it?

Comment: Just adjust the size of the memo[][] table to be that of the max boundary size. What is the max length you can go to? Also,can i and j go negative? I that case, we can use `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks Shreyans, I'm now trying both yours and Andrea's codes. I don't understand why they both crash, I'm really trying hard to understand but I don't get it! Any hint?

Comment: Both are codes are the same. Care to post your entire code at http://ideone.com/ and post a link here?

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer. It works for me. Just increased the size to n+1. :) Here is the code that works: http://ideone.com/9yiOBI

Comment: That was fast! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I accepted your answer but can't upvote yet because I don't have enough reputation

Comment: That's ok. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

> But I can't understand [...] why it would make the function more efficient.

Looking at the image, numbering the pictures starting with 1, and `(x,y)` coordinates with `(0,0)` in lower left corner, you can see that pictures 2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,10, 12, are all going through the point at `(3,1)`.

Paths from `(3,1)`:

- `(3,1) → (4,1) ↑ (4,2) ↑ (4,3) ↑ (4,4)`

  - Picture 2, 4, 5
- `(3,1) ↑ (3,2) → (4,2) ↑ (4,3) ↑ (4,4)`

  - Picture 3, 6, 8
- `(3,1) ↑ (3,2) ↑ (3,3) → (4,3) ↑ (4,4)`

  - Picture 7, 10, 12

As you can see, you're walking the same path multiple (3) times. If you could cache (memoize) the fact that there are 3 paths from `(3,1)` to the end, you're saving time.

Time savings will grow as the grid gets bigger.

[image: Catalan number 4x4 grid example]

---

So, what you do, is that first time you get to a point, you calculate the result using recursion, as you already do, then save the number for that point, and when getting to the point again, you just use the cached value:

```
public static long paths(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    return paths(n, 0, 0, new long[n][n]);
}
private static long paths(int n, int y, int x, long[][] cache) {
    long result = cache[y][x];
    if (result == 0) {
        if (y < x && x < n) // CAN MOVE UP & RIGHT
            result = paths(n, y + 1, x, cache) + paths(n, y, x + 1, cache);
        else if (y < x) // CAN MOVE UP
            result = paths(n, y + 1, x, cache);
        else if (x < n) // CAN MOVE RIGHT
            result = paths(n, y, x + 1, cache);
        else // CAN'T MOVE
            result = 1;
        cache[y][x] = result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I had downvoted your answer because you had not answered the question completely. Only given an explanation. I believe that your and my answer would make a good combination though. So i reversed it

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Code added

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't understand why but this is also crashing (for n = 4, it crashes when (x < n) )... I'm trying to understand why but I can't manage to, my head kinda exploded!

Comment: Alright I got it, that was because the array should have been `n+1 x n+1` . Thank you again for your help an effort!