# My recursive function for finding the number of paths in a grid runs infinitely

Tags: java, recursion, graph

I'm working on a couple of Project Euler problems and want to test my solution. My recursive function never ends even with reachable base cases.

in a 20x20 grid I am using x and y coordinates to navigate up and left to find the number of paths from (19,19) to (0,0). My base case is to return 1 when we reach (0,0). Otherwise I add the current count to the recursive call.

Function:

```
private static int numPaths(int x, int y, int pathsFound)
{
    if(x == 0 && y == 0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        if(x > 0)
        {
            pathsFound += numPaths(x - 1, y, pathsFound);
        }
        if(y > 0)
        {
            pathsFound += numPaths(x, y - 1, pathsFound);
        }
    }
    return pathsFound;
}
```

Main:

```
int x = 19;
int y = 19;
System.out.println("Answer: " + numPaths(x, y, 0));
```

Is there a flaw in my recursive logic, or is just taking a very long time to compute? If you know the solution to this Euler problem, please do not post it.

https://projecteuler.net/problem=15

Comment: How long have you let this run? Eventually you'll hit a stack overflow if it truly is an infinite recursion. Situations like these are best handled using a debugger and stepping through the recursive calls line by line.

Comment: why `numPaths(x - 1, y - 1, pathsFound);`? You never will be able to walk in a diagonal

Comment: Pure recursion won't cut it. Too many paths that you keep recalculating over and over.  Either use recursion with caching or dynamic programming.

Comment: @PedroH wow great point. I wasn't thinking grid terms, only numerical neighboring.

Comment: @schwobaseggl ahhhh, so it does just take a very long time to compute. Thanks I'll look into a DP solution.

Comment: @Programatic  Why not just add a cache when you already have the recursive code?

Comment: You problem is very similar to [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34244383/5221149), which uses [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), or caching as @schwobaseggl called it. It has nice picture to illustrate the point. --- To see the problem of not using memoization, try running with a smaller grid (2x2), then increase the size (3x3, 4x4, 5x5, ...), and check the result for each, and you'll see why it begins running slooooowwwww by the time you get to 20x20.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I looked into memoization, and wow did it increase efficiency! Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @Programatic Imagine, in languages like e.g. `Python`, you can just write a little `memo` decorator, and, boom, one line of code makes every recursive function memoized ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone is interested, I looked into memoization and came up with an elegant solution without recursion.

Function:

```
private static BigInteger numberPaths(ArrayList<ArrayList<BigInteger>> grid)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 20; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 20; ++j)
        {
            int x = j;
            int y = i;
            if(x - 1 < 0 || y - 1 < 0)
            {
                grid.get(x).set(y, BigInteger.ONE);
            }
            else
            {
                BigInteger topVal = grid.get(x - 1).get(y);
                BigInteger leftVal = grid.get(x).get(y - 1);
                grid.get(x).set(y, topVal.add(leftVal));
            }

        }
    }
    return grid.get(20).get(20); //the solution
}
```

Main:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<BigInteger>> grid = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 20; ++i)
{
    ArrayList<BigInteger> column = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 0; j <= 20; ++j)
    {
        column.add(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
    }
    grid.add(column);
 }
System.out.println("Answer: " + numberPaths(grid));
```